# Use of rook polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, permutations, algebraic-combinatorics

Use rook polynomials to count the number of permutations of $(1,2,3,4)$ in which $1$ is not in the second position, $2$ is not in the fourth position, and $3$ is not in the first or fourth position. How do we solve this one? Do we first calculate the rook polynomials of forbidden positions and then subtract?

Comment: What is the board you're working with? Where are these "first, second, third, fourth" positions?  Providing a diagram would get you more responses from here.

Comment: The question doesn't mention any other thing but I think it's supposed to be 4 by 4 board and #1 cannot be in the second position of 1st row, 2 cannot be in the 4th position of 2nd row and 3 cannot be in the 1st or 4th position in 3rd row. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: Do you know the formula that gives the number of restricted permutations of $[n]$ as $\Sigma_{k=0}^n(-1)^k r_k(B)(n-k)!$ where $r_k(B)$ is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the rook polynomial for the forbidden board? I hesitate to present this is an answer since it strictly uses only the coefficients of the rook polynomial.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest thing to do would be to draw out your diagram first. Given the information in the problem as stated, a reasonable chess board would be given as

[image: Image of Chess board without re-ordering]

For this chess board, the numbers on the left column represent the numbers to be permuted, the numbers along the top row represent the positions that a number can go to. A square that is shaded red is a forbidden region (for example, the square at row 1, column 2 is forbidden since you state in the problem description that the number 1 can not go to position #2).

We can reorganize the columns to make a chess board that is easier to work with like the one below.

[image: Image of chess board with reordered columns.]

Seeing as there are far fewer forbidden positions than allowed positions, your guess that counting the number of ways to place a number into a forbidden position, and then subtracting from the total number of ways to permute the numbers is actually a good idea.

Because of the way I reordered the chess board, determining the rook polynomials for the forbidden regions is relatively easy.

The rook polynomial for the red square at row 1, column 2 is (1 + x). The rook polynomial for the other forbidden region is (1 + 3x + x<sup>2</sup>). Seeing as both of these regions are disjoint (meaning that neither region shares a row or a column), we simply multiply both polynomials together, yielding

1 + 4x + 4x<sup>2</sup> + x<sup>3</sup>

We now use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion to count the number of possible arrangements where no number gets sent to a forbidden position.

Let r<sub>k</sub> be the coefficient of x<sup>k</sup> in the rook polynomial (1 + 4x + 4x<sup>2</sup> + x<sup>3</sup>).

Without regard to forbidden positions, there are r<sub>0</sub>(4!) = 1 * 4! ways to permute the numbers.

We now subtract off the number of permutations where at least one number is in a forbidden position, given by r<sub>1</sub>(3!) = 4*3!.

But we subtracted off twice as many permutations with at least 2 numbers in forbidden positions, so we must add on one of each, given by r<sub>2</sub>(2!) = 4*2!.

In adding on the previous term, we have twice counted the number of permutations with 3 of the numbers in forbidden positions, so we must subtract off those permutations one more time, given by r<sub>3</sub>(1!) = 1*1!.

The final answer is given by (1 * 4!) - (4 * 3!) + (4 * 2!) - (1 * 1!).

We could simplify: (1 * 4!) - (4 * 3!) + (4 * 2!) - (1 * 1!) = 24 - 24 + 8 - 1 = 7.

There are a total of 7 ways to permute the numbers 1,2,3,4 such that 1 does not go to position #2, 2 does not go to position #4, and 3 does not go to position #1 or position #4.